# Find the complex roots of $8z^3+27=0$ and thus find the area of the triangle

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

$8z^3+27=0$

So I took two approaches, and my answers are slightly different, so I was wondering which one was correct:
\begin{align*}
8z^3 & =-27\\
2z & = -3\\
z & = -\dfrac32
\end{align*}

$r=\dfrac32$

$\arg z = \arctan\left(\dfrac{0}{-3/2}\right) = 0$

$z = \dfrac32\operatorname{cis}\!\big(0 + 2\pi k\big)\,$, $\;\,k$ is a positive integer

**second approach**

$z^3 = -\dfrac{27}8$

$r=\dfrac{27}8$

$\arg z = 0$

$z^{1/3} = \left(\dfrac{27}8\right)^{\!1/3}\!\operatorname{cis}\left(\dfrac{0 +2\pi k}{3}\right)$

$z =\dfrac32\operatorname{cis}\left(\dfrac{2 \pi k}{3}\right)$

Area of the triangle:
$\dfrac12ab\sin(c)=\dfrac12\left(\dfrac32\right)^{\!2}\!\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)\approx0.041$

Comment: Did you try cubing your results to see if they work?

Comment: The second approach is ok, provided you define "cis"(x) as $e^{ix}.$ The first one is not, because a non-zero complex number has 3 cube roots, not only one. Note that the " 3/2 cis (pi + 2pik)" of your first approach are the particular case of the "z = (3/2) cis (pi+2pi$\ell$)/3" of your second approach when $\ell=3k+1$

Comment: @CyclotomicField Both "work", that was not the problem. Oh wait, I think I understand your hint. Since ($*$): *the solutions of the first approach are only a part of the solutions of the 2nd approach*, and the latter "work", the first approach is not "correct" in the sense that it does not give *all* solutions. Is that what you meant? But I am not sure the OP noticed ($*$).

Comment: This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I tried to correct your formatting.  However, $\arg z = \arctan\left(\frac{0}{\frac{3}{2}}\right) = \pi$ does not make sense since $\arctan(0) = 0$.  What did you intend to write?

Comment: Thank you. Yes you’re right it should be 0

Comment: I made an edit to include finding the area, though this number seems very small and i’m not sure it’s correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval I didn't actually look at the specifics of the problem, I just wanted to give them a means to move forward. Pedagogically speaking, students often ask "Is $x$ in the kernel of $\varphi$?" under many guises and my first question is always "Did you calculate $\varphi (x)$?" Sometimes we just get lost in the complications and forget the simple things.

Comment: In all these cases, with a simple cube root operation, just find the single real root, call it $r$. The other two complex roots are $r\omega$ and $r\omega^2$, where $\omega$ is a complex cube root of $1$, easily found by solving $x^2 + x+1 = 0$ and taking either root.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=Re^{i\theta}$, where $R\in[0,\infty)$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, Then, $$R^3e^{i\cdot3\theta} = -\dfrac{27}{8}\Rightarrow R=\dfrac{3}{2} \enspace \text{and} \enspace \theta \in \left\{\dfrac{\pi}{3},\pi,\dfrac{5\pi}{3}\right\}$$ Hence, the solution is $\dfrac{3}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}, \dfrac{3}{2}e^{i\pi}\enspace \text{or} \enspace \dfrac{3}{2}e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}$.

Answer (score 1):

A more usual notation for [cis(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis_(mathematics)) is $e^{ix}.$

The second approach is ok but you can restrict explicitely the values of $k$ to three consecutive integers (e.g. $-1,0,1$), to avoid redundancy.

The first one is not, mainly because a non-zero complex number has three cube roots, not only one, so you missed 2 solutions out of 3. (Also, as noted by @N.F.Taussig, "$\arg z = \arctan(\frac{0}{-3/2}) = \pi$" makes no sense. Replace it by "$\arg z = \arg(-3/2) = \pi$". And "$k$ is a positive integer" can be replaced by $k=0$ without missing more solutions.)

Note that the $z=\frac32e^{i(1+2k)\pi}$ of your first approach are the particular case of the $z=\frac32e^{i\frac{1+2\ell}3\pi}$ of your second approach when $ℓ=3k+1.$ Since (as you can check by cubing them, following @CyclotomicField's advice) the latter are true solutions, this is another way to realize that former are not *all* the solutions.